# how to add navigationcontroller to uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone

```
employeeDetailed  = [[[EmployeeDetailedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EmployeeDetailedViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:employeeDetailed] autorelease];
    [employeeDetailed release];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

I try this its saying bad access.[crash]

how to reslove this issue.

@ thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // Set the view controller as the window's root view controller and display.
    UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}



employeeDetailed  = [[[EmployeeDetailedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EmployeeDetailedViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

[self. navigationController presentModalViewController: navController];
```

This will work for you try this.

Answer (score 1):

You have autorelease set in the first line (alloc/init)

You are then explicitly releasing the view controller on line three.

You are therefore over-releasing this object and causing the crash.

You can remove the **[employeeDetailed release]** line and it will be fine.

Comment: @thanks IanL forget memory issue.! can you help me out how to pushViewController its not pushing for me

Comment: As beryllium mentioned, you cannot push a new UINavigationController onto an existing navigation stack. You refer to self.navigationController, so I assume that the current controller is part of a stack. In which case you should be able to simply use: [self.navigationController pushViewController:employeeDetailed animated:YES];

Comment: yeap i used  [self.navigationController pushViewController:employeeDetailed animated:YES];  still the controller is not doing any thing!

Comment: does self.navigationController exist? i.e. Are you sure that the current controller is part of a navigation stack?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add UINavigationController to existed navigation stack. Instead of you need to show new navigation controller modal like this:

```
employeeDetailed  = [[[EmployeeDetailedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EmployeeDetailedViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:employeeDetailed] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController: navController];
```

Comment: i do not want presentmodalviewcontroller sir. I need the pushViewController

Comment: then push only `employeeDetailed`, without `navController`.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way I found to present Navigation Controller in a specific part in your Application is like these:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]initwithnibname :@"MyViewController"];
    UINavigationController *myNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
```

Then in your myViewController.m
use

```
[self.NavigationController pushViewController: XController animated:YES];
```